# Data selection and filtering in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to write a routine that returns only *unanimous* votings with only the roll call ids where all voting countries voted with "yes".

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(unvotes)

unvotes %>%
  filter(vote == 'yes')
by_country <- unvotes %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarize(votes = n(),
            percent_yes = mean(vote == "yes"))
```

Not quite sure how to populate just the `rcid` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```r
unvotes %>% group_by( rcid ) %>%
    summarise( votes=n(), percent_yes = sum(vote=="yes")/n() ) %>%
    filter( percent_yes == 1 )
```

I'm assuming each row has a `rcid`, a `country` and a `vote` that is either yes or no.